# React Native - Single select in Flatlist

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to make a simple button with text where if a user taps on it, it would change it's colour and text. This button with text is displayed in my **Flatlist** I can now change the text on it if it is tapped, but the problem is the other buttons with text in my **Flatlist** is also changing.

What I'am targeting is to change the single button that will be tapped.

Here's my code.

```
export default class tables extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            ...
            toggle: true,
        }
    }
    _onPress() {
        const newState = !this.state.toggle;
        this.setState({ toggle: newState })
    }
    render() {
        const { toggle } = this.state;
        const textValue = toggle?"Available":"Occupied";
        const buttonBg = toggle?"dodgerblue":"white";
        const textColor = toggle?"white":"black";
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                ....
                renderItem = {({ item }) => 
                    <View>
                        <Text>Table No: { item.tbl_id }</Text>

                        <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress = { () => this._onPress()}>
                            <Text>{textValue}</Text>              // Button with text
                        </TouchableHighlight>

                            <View>
                                <TouchableHighlight
                                ....>
                                    <Text>DINE-IN</Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight>

                                <TouchableHighlight
                                ....
                                    <Text>TAKE-OUT</Text>
                                </TouchableHighlight> 
                            </View>
                    </View>
                }
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The  `toggle: true,` value must be in the `item`

Actually your bollean affect all the items present in data. Your item should look like this:

```
data: [
 { itemName: 'hi', toggle: false, id: 1 },
 { itemName: 'hey', toggle: false, id: 2 },
 // others items
]
```

then, your onPress:

```
 onPress = (id) => {
    const { data } = this.state
    data.forEach((elem) => {
      elem.toggle = false
      if (elem.id === id) {
        elem.toggle = true
      }
    })
    this.setState({ data })
  }
```

In the map:

```
<TouchableHighlightonPress = { () => this._onPress(item.id)}>
<Text>{item.toggle ? "Available" : "Occupied"}</Text>
```

You could do it in another way by storing the `item.id` in `this.state.toggle` and then have something easier:

```
 onPress = (id) => {
   this.setState({ toggle: id })  
 }

<Text>{item.id === this.state.toggle ? "Occupied": "Available" }</Text>
```

Comment: Sir, you mean like this? renderItem = {({ item, toggle: true }) ? Sorry, I'am a first timer.

Comment: You just need to have a toggle entry in your item object, and then put to true onPress and put all others to false